# Combine columns from two files if they match, R

Tags: r, pattern-matching

Given two files where the ID from file1 can be found in file2, I want to make a combined file which include match IDs.

Is the merge-function in R simply the solution?

File1:

```
 ID                                    start end
 mmu-miR-101b-3p_GTACAGTACTGTGATAGCTGA 60   80
 mmu-miR-101b-3p_GTACAGTACTGTGATAGCTG  60   80
 mmu-miR-30a-3p_TTTCAGTCGGATGTTTGCAGC  48   68
 mmu-miR-30a-3p_CTTTCAGTCGGATGTTTGCAGC 47   68
```

File2:

```
ID                                      FC
mmu-miR-101b-3p_GTACAGTACTGTGATAGCTGA   5.9491448553
mmu-miR-10a-5p_TACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTGT 5.321215412
mmu-miR-322-5p_CAGCAGCAATTCATGTTTTGGA   5.233658301
mmu-miR-10b-5p_TACCCTGTAGAACCGAATTTGT   4.927861459
```

Output:

```
mmu-miR-101b-3p_GTACAGTACTGTGATAGCTGA   5.9491448553 mmu-miR-101b-3p_GTACAGTACTGTGATAGCTGA 60   80
```

Comment: Yes, it's called `merge` and you can read all about it with `?merge` :)

Comment: Why did my output from merge(file1, file2) become 150MB??

Comment: How big are the individual files? The merge could not be larger than the sum of the two. It would help if you would include a small code example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I just had to give the column that should be merged similar IDs in the two files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use merge (which will work), just:

```
x1 <- x1[x1$ID %in% intersect(x1$ID, x2$ID), ]
x2 <- x2[x2$ID %in% intersect(x1$ID, x2$ID), ]
x1 <- x1[order(x1$ID), ]
x2 <- x2[order(x1$ID), ]
x1 <- x1[! duplicated(x1$ID), ]
x2 <- x2[! duplicated(x2$ID), ]
merged <- cbind(x1, x2)
```

Where x1 and x2 are the dataframes for files 1 and 2.

But. Srsly. Just read the ?merge page <3